# How do content publishers maintain a similar UX on different devices?

Tags: android, pdf, doc, kindle, nook

How do developers able to handle publishing their stuff on devices with different screen sizes (and even different dimension ratios)?

For instance I own an old 10" and a newer 6" kindle. For some ebooks, the placement of pictures and the text differ radically (especially one encounters  this type of stuff frequently with academic books), and yet the content always seamlessly adopt to the environment. I wonder how this is maintained on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my perspective as a kindle author and a wannabe kindle comicbook author.

Amazon provides multiple desktop publishing tools- one for regular ebooks, another for publishing textbooks and yet another for the more artistic, picture-heavy stuff.

All of them let you preview how your content would appear on a host of devices, I use it as a simulator to check the formatting and then fix things. Also, not using pdf or ps versions, and rather converting them to docx and then publishing using these tools helps for some reason.